# Create Powershell Session is failed using OAuth

Tags: powershell, office365

Trying to change a script from basic authentication to Exchange Online V2 Module to utilise Modern Auth.

```
Install-Module PowershellGet -Force
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser

# Install and test
Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement

Get-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement -ListAvailable

$UserCredential = Get-Credential

Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $UserCredential -ShowProgress $true
```

The Error im getting is

> New-ExoPSSession : Create Powershell Session is failed using OAuth

I've tried removing and reinstalling the module, Which didn't work
I've tried this script on a different machine, Which worked
I've tried setting the proxy parameters to null, Which didn't work
I've tried using the code on the microsoft doc to only utilise modern auth and not Two factor, Didnt work

I've mainly used this a source, but have looked around in different places to find the answer but no luck.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same thing happen to me.  I had to enable winrm.

I used:
winrm quickconfig

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/installation-and-configuration-for-windows-remote-management#quick-default-configuration

Then I had to enable basic auth for WinRM
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WinRM\Client]
"AllowBasic"=dword:00000001

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b514abea-ab42-429d-bce5-a96274868927/winrm-basic-authentication-is-currently-disabled-quotallowbasicquotdword00000001

After that I was able to connect without that error.

Comment: I'll Give it a Try and let you know :)

Comment: Worked like a charm, Had to start the service also but seems to be working fine now. Must have been some group policy thing through work. Thank you James